# Tagging certain rows based on date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, date

I currently have data that is tagged with a specific date. I want to sort this data by adding a column that states whether the date is within the last month, within the last 2-3 months, or older than 3 months.

Currently my dates are stored in the table like this:

```
 Date
 ----
 06/28/2018
 06/21/2018
 05/19/2014
 05/02/2018
```

And I'd like the data to look like this:

```
 Date          DateTag
 ----          -------
 06/28/2018    Last Month
 06/21/2018    Last Month
 05/19/2014    Over 3 Months
 05/02/2018    Last 3 Months
```

Does anyone have an SQL solution on how to tag and sort by dates like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select date,
       (case when date <= curdate() and date > curdate() - interval 1 month
             then 'within 1 month'
             when date <= curdate() - interval 1 month and date > curdate() - interval 2 month
             then '2-3 months ago'
             when date <= curdate() - interval 3 month
             then '3+ months ago'
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: I'm running into issues with this statement `curdate() - interval 1 month`, is it possible that the way my date is formatted doesn't allow this statement to be run?

Comment: @BobDuncan The datatype for the `date` field should be `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: If it isn't, you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse it.

Comment: @BobDuncan . . . `curdate() - interval 1 month` definitely works in MySQL and has for many, many versions.

Comment: @Barmar The STR_TO_DATE() method fixed my issues, I did not have the date field using the correct DATE datatype. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test_dates (
    date DATE
);

insert into test_dates values('2018-06-28'),('2018-06-21'),('2014-05-19'),('2018-05-02');

SELECT 
    date,
    CASE
        WHEN date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) AND NOW() THEN 'Last Month'
        WHEN date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 90 DAY) AND NOW() THEN 'Last 3 Months'
        WHEN date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) THEN 'Over 3 Months'
    END AS DateTag
FROM
    test_dates;
```

Comment: Ran this, but every single item came out tagged as 'Over 3 Months'